# Passing different parameters to a Swift timer each time it is fired

Tags: swift, timer, http-get

I have a number of HTTP GET requests to be scheduled at every 100 ms.

It seems that using Timer + LoopRun is a good solution. However, each time the timer is fired, the parameter passed to it is different.

I know how to pass the same parameter (e.g., https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/117/the-ultimate-guide-to-timer ) but I don't find an answer in the scenario where a different parameter is passed each time the timer is fired.

Comment: Any reason you can't request  all the api calls inside the method fired by one timer?

Comment: A lot of times, mobile phones have a latency over 100ms, with high variance. Making web requests 10/s makes little sense. What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: @luckystars  The API I'm using allows only 1 request per 100ms.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica many web service providers limit the request rate, otherwise, their server will be overloaded. it's kind of like Deny of Service cyber attack if you don't limit your request rate. I want to make sure that, at least my code will not send request more than 1 per 100ms.

Comment: @Feng So the 100ms is a limit, not a goal? As in, you want to make sure that your web requests go through, but never more frequently than every 100ms?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Yes, a limit. Now I have a new issue. Some of the requests seem to be lost (i.e., the completion handler was never executed).

Comment: Then I would suggest you heavily edit your question, because the first sentence " have a number of HTTP GET requests to be scheduled at every 100 ms." clearly states you're looking to set a target rate, not a limit.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica My question was about how to pass different parameters each time, as indicated in the title. Thanks for your time though!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out with the hint from an iOS slack channel.

use a counter inside your selector, served as the index to my parameter array. when the counter changes, it will point to the next element in the parameter array. I can access the next parameter in my selector. Here is the code

```
@objc func timedSearch(timer:Timer){
    if searchCnt == flightCandidates?.count { // stop timer
        timer.invalidate()
        return
    }
    let flight = flightCandidates![searchCnt]
        flightSearch(flightCandidate: flight)
    searchCnt += 1
}
```